# 'requestAnimationFrame' handler took <N>ms in lightningchart

Tags: lightningchart

If i run large sets of data , that is 5 charts with 1000's of points per second.. chart gets freezed for few milli seconds.

```
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 33ms
```

and another error

```
[Violation] 'requestAnimationFrame' handler took <N>ms
```

I am using macbook pro M1 chip , its pretty fast. is there any way to prevent this lag.

Comment: The 'requestAnimationFrame' handler took <N>ms is normal warning by browser when an frame rendering takes more than ~16ms. It's expected that rendering a single frame can take longer than that when there is lot to render and process.